# It is possible to make %%i into a %variable%

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So i have this code:

```
@echo off
pause
for /F %%i in ('dir /b "C:\PSTCheck\*txt"') do (

   echo Folder is NON empty
   echo %%i
   pause
)
```

Is possible to make the `%%i` into a `%variable%` so i can use this loop in other codes, for example check the file sizes??

Comment: `set variable=%%i` - You will need to use delayed expansion to use the variable inside your FOR command.

Comment: You may use `%%i` in any code where you can use a variable. However, you can _not_ check the file size from a variable, just from a `%%~Zi` FOR parameter.

Comment: You can also `call` a local label, passing in a filename and use `%~z1` inside that to access the size.

Answer (score -2):

Before the for loop

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Inside the for loop

```
set MyVariable=%%i
```

Comment: The assignment to a var doesn't require delayed expansion, the usage of the vars content inside a (code block) does require it.